# Unable to load the file or assembly to use class XSSFWorkbook in NPOI library

Tags: .net, vb.net, npoi

I'm using the `NPOI` library to read a `.xlsx` document and convert to `dataSet`. When I try to instantiate the class `XSSFWorkbook`, I  get an error.

My code:

```
Dim file As New FileStream(myFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
Dim oDs As New List(Of entity.myFile)
Dim libro As New XSSFWorkbook(file)
```

I obtain the following error:

```
Unable to load the file or assembly  'ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib,
Version=0.86.0.518, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b03e6acf1164f73'
or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the specified
file.
```

what's wrong here?

Comment: Which version of NPOI are you using? You may need to update NPOI to fix this issue. See the bug fixes in release notes of [version 2.4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/2.4.0).

Comment: I using the version 2.0.5 of NPOI

Comment: Do you have SharpZipLib v.0.86.0 installed?

Comment: Thank you so much! I needed to add the dependence SharpZibLib